# How can i create double sided composite primary key in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a table and this table has relationship with itself as many-to-many. So i am create another table (second table) that stores two id for composite primary key which comes from  original (first) table. But if in second table there is id1=1 and id2=2, then second table  shouldn't have id1=2 and id2=1. 
So how can i do that, should i write a trigger for that or is there a simple way for oracle.
I use Oracle11g and pl/sql developer.

Comment: "if this table then this table"? Huh? if a table contains some records, it SHOULDN'T contain those records? you need to be clearer about which tables you're talking about. "This table" is not clear at all.

Comment: I am edited explanation.

Comment: Maybe just add a constraint that id1 < id2?

Comment: It maybe work I try that thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try defining a unique function-based index that automatically defines the index in numerical order. This would ensure that only one of the 2 combinations is ever allowed.  Something like:

```
create unique index your_index on your_table(
    least(id1, id2),
    greatest(id1, id2)
);
```

If it matters, there is a slight difference between this approach and MT0's answer that uses the check constraint.

With the check constraint approach, only `(id1=1, id2=2)` is valid.

With the function-based index approach, both `(id1=1, id2=2)` and `(id1=2, id2=1)` are valid, but they can't both be present in the table at any given time.

Comment: This can be done easier using `least()` and `greatest()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, thank you. That's what I wanted to use, but wasn't sure what functions I can use in a function-based index.  I went safe until I can test.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE table_name_many_to_many(
  id1 INT REFERENCES table_name( id ),
  id2 INT REFERENCES table_name( id ),
  CONSTRAINT tnmtm__id1__id2__pk PRIMARY KEY ( id1, id2 ),
  CONSTRAINT tnmtm__id1__id2__chk CHECK ( id1 <= id2 )
);
```